# What does __new__ do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have seen the use of `__new__` in several answers across the site, especially in things like:

```
super().__new__(*args)
```

Whereas I use:

```
super().__init__(*args)
```

- Is it similar to `__init__`?
- Is it even a method?
- Which should a beginner use?

Comment: in short, `__new__` is a constructor where as `__init__` is an initializer (works on an existing objects, that's why you already have `self`). See @Lix 's suggestion.

Comment: @Lix Thanks! That clears it up.

Comment: @Mutantoe - no problem :) Happy to help! Once you have enough rep points, go ahead and give an upvote to the user who provided the actual answer - this is the best way of showing your appreciation on [so].